# C# Convert a PublicKey to string and vice-versa

Tags: c#, public-key

We are using PublicKeys in C#. We are need to store and retrieve them from a sql database. At the moment I am storing them as a string and I am not able to convert the string back to a public key token.

If you may please help me understand how to do so? Or if there is a better way of implementing the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of "thanks you" please provide code sample that shows what you've tried and have problem with. Otherwise impossible to suggest what is wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean converting to and from a X.509v3 certificate, check out the [PublicKey class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an x.509 certificate check out the X509Certificate2 class. There is an `Import` method you can use to load up your key from a `string` or `byte[]`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148438(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)